# Why am I getting ORA-00904: invalid identifier error?

Tags: database, oracle

Why does this throw  ORA-00904: invalid identifier error?

```
CREATE TABLE CREDITCARD(
CREDITCARDNO VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
CARDNAME VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
CARDEXPIRY VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT CREDIT_CARD_ID_PK PRIMARY KEY(CREDITCARDNO),
);
```

Comment: Remove the last comma

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the last comma, it's that the error

Answer (score 0):

you should omit last comma:

```
CREATE TABLE CREDITCARD(
CREDITCARDNO VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
CARDNAME VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
CARDEXPIRY VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT CREDIT_CARD_ID_PK PRIMARY KEY(CREDITCARDNO) --<--no comma here
);
```